# ASP.NET - How to handle programmaticaly broken URLs ended with dot characters?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Our application gets requests with broken URLs ended with dot character, i.e. "/examle." , "/example..", etc. from time to time. As for now, such requests end up with standard IIS 404 error ("Server Error in '/' Application."), which is default behavior, and seem not to reach ASP.NET application at all. By some reason I need to set IIS to pass such requests to the application, where they should be handled in a custom way. Is there any way to achieve this?

We use ASP.NET Web Forms, IIS 7 and .NET Framework 4

Comment: Related: [If the URL is “.” To the end, I can‘t jump to the errorpage in asp.net IIS 7.5+](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22554651/1154184)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom page for error 404, for example 404.aspx and decalre it in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
.
.
.
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/404.aspx" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

And dot problem can be fixed if you are ond .NET 4.0 or later with this setting:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

Comment: Made this. Regular non-existing pages are redirected to this custom page, but again not these which end with ".".

Comment: Thank you Antonio, relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" works!